# crypto-js Uncaught Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I used crypto in node ,like below，it works well.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
let key = aesConf.key;
let iv = aesConf.iv;
var cipherChunks = []
var decipher = crypto2.createDecipheriv('des-ecb', key, iv);
decipher.setAutoPadding(true)
cipherChunks.push(decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8'))
cipherChunks.push(decipher.final('utf8'));
return cipherChunks.join('')
```

But when I use cryptoJS, like below, it can not work,and i get 'Uncaught Error: Malformed UTF-8 data'

```
 var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
            iv: iv
        });
   var result_value = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Could anybody help me resolve this problem or tell me why